# Magento Collection Filter

Tags: magento

I am working on module to create magento product via front end and by customers, everything finished and working fine, I have a new attribute set in the product named product_reviewed (1 for reviewed , 0 for not reviewed), its an status field for product which indicate whether the product is reviewed by admin or not,
Now I want to hide all product which are not reviewed (product_reviewed=0), in the front end part of the magento site , Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this. I mean by default Magento front end show all product which is status published, but as an extent to that I want to add a global filter which will also hide which is not reviewed by admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to determine to show or not - you need to rewrite such method.
In your case you need to rewrite

Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::canShow

or

Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::isVisibleInCatalog

Also you can check this attribute (using helper) on your template

Comment: Overriding the following method [Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::isVisibleInCatalog]  with rewrite of core class works fine for individual product view, but those products still appears in list view, featured products, etc...
what can I do to filter list view as well, I tried with an event observer for [catalogProductCollectionLoadBefore] with no avail

Comment: I tried to debug a few, I found following:
Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection
Here executing two deprecated methods
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);      Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);